# how to print do while output in C programming according to how many user choose to give an input again

Tags: c

As in picture, the user choose to enter again, there will be 2 different age and name in the output instead 1, how to print the output according to the user choose to input it again

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int age, again;
    char name[20];
    do{
    printf("please enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("want to input again? 1=yes, 2=no: ");
    scanf("%d", &again);


    }while(again==1);

    printf("name:%s", name);
    printf("\nage: %d", age);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Use `array` and store all the inputs in it. Using array of `structure` is better one.

Comment: A better title would attract the right people to help you and would make this discussion easyer to find for users of our knowledge base.

Comment: then display the output using for loop? @kiranBiradar

Comment: @AlifIskandarAzura Yes. Maintain a counter to count how many inputs user has inputted.

Comment: @DirkHorsten im sorry sir, im new to this.. will make improvement on title after this

Comment: @kiranBiradar but, how i can store the input from the user for the age and name, do i need to insert for loop  for the input?

Comment: A better solution is to create a `struct` to coordinate `name, age` for each entry (e.g. `struct person { char name[20]; int age; };` and then create an array of `struct person` (e.g. `struct person people[10];` which will create any array of 10 `struct person`), then just loop `while (count < 10) { /* prompt, fill people[n].name, people[n].age, n++ */ }`. Then you can loop `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` outputting `people[i].name` and `people[i].age`, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it. I think your problem will solve now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_INPUT 10
int main()
{
  int  again,i;
  int counter=0;
  char name[MAX_INPUT][20];
  int age[MAX_INPUT];

 do{
   printf("please enter age: ");
   scanf("%d", &age[counter]);

   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%s", &name[counter]);

   printf("want to input again? 1=yes, 2=no: ");
   scanf("%d", &again);
   counter++;
 }while(again==1);
   for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
     printf("\nname:%s", name[i]);
     printf("\nage: %d", age[i]);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if a *matching failure* occurs when you attempt to take integer input? How would you know?

Comment: Yeah...then the error will come up if you entered wrong input. For this, you have to handle the errors.

Comment: Really big thanks! it worked like i expected! but could u explain to me the uses of MAX_INPUT. thank you

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is correct then I would able to help more

Comment: `MAX_INPUT is a global variable` Are you sure it is a variable? Don't feed wrong to newbie.

Comment: @alif-iskandar-azura sorry for some wrong information. Please check the following link. There are more details about [Macro.](https://www.javatpoint.com/c-macros)

Answer (score 1):

Store all the inputs in array of `structure` and read the inputs in it.

Once you are done with the input, print the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typdef struct
{
   int age;
   char name[20];
} input;

int main()
{
    int again;
    int totalInp = 0;
    int inputSize = 100;
    input *pInp = malloc(inputSize * sizeof(*pInp));


    do{
        if (totalInp >= inputSize )
        {
            inputSize  += 100;
            pInp = realloc(pInp, sizeof(*pInp)*inputSize);
        }

        printf("please enter age: ");
        scanf("%d", &pInp[totalInp].age);

        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%19s", &pInp[totalInp].name);

        totalInp++;

        printf("want to input again? 1=yes, 2=no: ");
        scanf("%d", &again);

    }while(again==1);

   for (int i=0; i < totalInp; i++)
   {
       printf("name:%s", pInp[i].name);
       printf("\nage: %d", pInp[i].age);
   }

   free(pInp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Duh, my bad on the `realloc` -- I must be going blind as I get old... Ignore that part -- but concentrate on the `scanf` return `:)`

Comment: Thanks! but theres a lot of advanced declaration and terms there which i not learned yet,  but im really appreciate that, i need to study more about this..

Answer (score 0):

```
  printf("name:%s", name);
  printf("\nage: %d", age);
```

Put this two statement inside `do` and run the code.

Comment: Please explain how this is supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: the output come after the user entered the input, in this case i need the output displayed after all the do while loop have finished, means until user choose no

Comment: At first, let me know,  what is your expected output?

Comment: For this type of output you need to maintain an array for storing name and age of all user . Maintain a counter which will incremented repeately after one user given input and then iterate over the output array to print name and age of all users

Comment: @PapanManna when user finish entering the input, it will ask to enter again or not, user will choose to enter it again, and again according to their need, but at the end when user choose no which is number 2, the output will be displayed according how much user give the input